# Calcular e imprimir promedio de un conjunto calificaciones asociadas a un alumno

Tags: php, sql-server, php7, mssql

En el siguiente codigo lo que estoy realizando es traer la boleta de calificaciones de cierto alumno, dependiendo del cuatrimestre que se haya elegido me trae un conjunto de **n** cantidad de materias con su respectiva calificacion, todo esto lo imprime en una tabla como en la siguente imagen.

El problema esta en que no me muestra el resultado de **promedio** correcto, se supone que mi array debe recorrer y obtener la cantidad de elementos que son las calificaciones sumarlas y dividirlas entre la cantidad obtenida. Realmente no se que hice mal para que genere este problema, lo que yo quiero lograr es que dependiendo de la cantidad de calificaciones me imprima el promedio.

Comment: La variable $suma esa dentro del while, por lo tanto su valor en cada vuelta es 0, lo que deberia hacerse es acumular las calificaciones, para eso tu variable $suma debe estar afuera del while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu variable $suma ponlo fuera del while

```
$suma = 0;
$contador_calificaciones = 0;
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {}
```

Luego dentro del while, no necesitas convertir la calificación a array,quedaria así

```
$suma += (int)$row['Calificacion'];
$contador_calificaciones++;
```

Luego para sacar el promedio,simplemente hacer esta operación,justo en el theader

```
<td colspan="3"><?php echo $suma/$contador_calificaciones?></td>
```

Comment: muchas gracias si me funciono a la perfección y entendi que hacia mal :)

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo que obtengas tus arreglos de la base de datos de esta forma:

```
$materias = [
   [
      'Clave' => '001',
      'Materia' => 'Biologia',
      'Calificacion' => '100'
   ],
   [
      'Clave' => '002',
      'Materia' => 'Matematicas',
      'Calificacion' => '100'
   ],
   [
      'Clave' => '003',
      'Materia' => 'Geografia',
      'Calificacion' => '100'
   ],
   [
      'Clave' => '004',
      'Materia' => 'Sociales',
      'Calificacion' => '95'
   ],
];
```

De esta forma se enreda uno menos y ahora el promedio es facil de sacar:

```
//Obtener el promedio
$totalMaterias = count($materias);
$totalCalification = 0;
foreach ($materias as $materia) {
   $totalCalification += $materia['Calificacion'];
}
$promedio = $totalCalification / $totalMaterias;
```

Por ultimo, separa el php del html para facilitar desplegar la informacion y se ve mas limpio el codigo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <table border="1">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>Clave</td>
            <td>Materia</td>
            <td>Calification</td>
         </tr>
         <?php foreach ($materias as $materia) : ?>
            <tr>
               <td><?php echo $materia['Clave']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $materia['Materia']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $materia['Calificacion']; ?></td>
            </tr>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Promedio</td>
            <td><?php echo $promedio; ?></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por su ayuda tomare en cuenta sus recomndaciones :)